# Are there any algorithms that can select identical elements that belong to the same clusters, which are obtained by different cluster analyses?

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-analysis

Consider a dataset where several clustering algorithms were applied.
E.g.  hierarhical clustering with different measures (average, single, complete, ward) and HDBSCAN with different number of points.

Is there any algorithm that identifies groups of elements belonging to the same cluster in all of the clustering results obtaied by different approaches?

Comment: Do you actually need an algorithm ? If you don't have hundreds of algorithms or clusters, maybe you can select the intersections of clusters obtained from different approaches ? This will give you points that were clustered together by all the algorithms

Answer (score 0):

Consensus or ensemble clustering does what I need - they combine multiple clustering models (partitions) into a single consolidated partition.